# SSL (indentation error) using virtualenvwrapper ( _lib.SSL_ST_INIT)

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I want to use then *--system-site-packages* parameter with *virtualenvwrapper*. But I've an SSL error :

```
$ mkvirtualenv --system-site-packages --python=`which python` my_env
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python
New python executable in /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_env/bin/python
Command /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_env/bin/python -m pip config list had error code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 793, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1088, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 935, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 964, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    config = _pip_config(py_executable, python_path)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1043, in _pip_config
    config[key] = ast.literal_eval(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Python : 2.7.9

My SSL config :

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ssl
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64            3.3.30-0+deb8u1                    amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  libio-socket-ssl-perl                2.002-2+deb8u3                     all          Perl module implementing object oriented interface to SSL sockets
ii  libnet-smtp-ssl-perl                 1.01-3                             all          Perl module providing SSL support to Net::SMTP
ii  libnet-ssleay-perl                   1.65-1+deb8u1                      amd64        Perl module for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
ii  libssl-doc                           1.0.1t-1+deb8u11                   all          Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development documentation
ii  libssl1.0.0:amd64                    1.0.1t-1+deb8u11                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  openssl                              1.0.1t-1+deb8u11                   amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
ii  python-openssl                       0.14-1                             all          Python 2 wrapper around the OpenSSL library
ii  ssl-cert                             1.0.35                             all          simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
```

I've a .so file in the dynamic lib. Here : */usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so*.

Answer (score -1):

I've just copied the .so file to the virtualenv folder :

```
cp /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```